# Is God the speaker of Psalm 102:25-27 or is it the psalmist David? Does the truth about this verse change if it's quoted in the New Testament?

Tags: creation

25 Beforetime the earth Thou didst found, And the work of Thy hands [are] the heavens.

26 They -- They perish, and Thou remainest, And all of them as a garment become old, As clothing Thou changest them, And they are changed.

27 And Thou [art] the same, and Thine years are not finished.

Is God  the speaker of Psalm 102:25-27 or is it the psalmist David? Does the truth about this verse change if it's quoted in the New Testament?

Comment: The speaker is the Holy Spirit in both OT and NT record. But that is a matter of interpretation.

Comment: @NigelJ. The scripture maybe inspired. But the bible also gives a record of who is speaking. Does both record show that the speaker is the holy spirit?

Comment: I have answered below in more detail.

Answer (score 2):

In the psalms, often, can be seen (if one has the faith and the discernment to see it) the voice of the Spirit speaking directly, as well as the Spirit speaking through the Psalmist.

This is a matter of interpretation in each specific place.

The words of the Psalmist, speaking spiritually, can be seen in verses 23 and 24 of Psalm 102 :

> He weakened my strength in the way; he shortened my days. I said, O my God, take me not away in the midst of my days: thy years are throughout all generations.

Ans the words of the Spirit peaking directly, through the Pslamist, by inspiration, can be seen in verses 25 to 28 :

> Of old hast thou laid the foundation of the earth: and the heavens are the work of thy hands. They shall perish, but thou shalt endure: yea, all of them shall wax old like a garment; as a vesture shalt thou change them, and they shall be changed: But thou art the same, and thy years shall have no end. The children of thy servants shall continue, and their seed shall be established before thee.

These last words are prophetic and inspirational, beyond the ability of natural humanity to discern by mere human intellect.

They are an utterance of the Holy Spirit, speaking through the Psalmist.

Answer (score 1):

Psalm 102:24 NKJV

> **I said**, “**O my God**, Do not take me away in the midst of my days; Your
> years are throughout all generations.

**Verse 24 addresses God directly. The speaker of Psalm 102 is not God, but rather the psalmist. Of course, all Scripture is inspired by God, so it’s arguable.** (2 Timothy 3:16-17)

What the psalmist is saying is that God is the Creator of all creation and that He is eternal and unchanging.

When someone quotes a verse from the Old Testament, it is often used to support certain theological points or to prove the fulfillment of prophecy. However, the original meaning of the verse and the context in which the verse is quoted do not change. If the someone were to quote the New Testament version of Psalm 102, it would still reflect the psalmist’s praise and recognition of God’s eternal nature and power.

Answer (score 1):

The first words in the first verse establish the speaker as a poor man (possibly David himself or any afflicted person)

> **1** **A prayer by a poor man** as he enwraps himself

Some verses speak *of* God while others speak directly *to* God.  There is not a single verse where God is speaking.

Answer (score 1):

The superscription of Ps 102 says this:

> A prayer of an afflicted person who has grown weak and pours out a
> lament before the LORD.

The entire prayer is spoken by the one praying.  It is part lament (V1-24a) and part praise to the LORD Jehovah (V24b-28).

Now to point of the question concerning Ps 102:25-27 and Heb 1:10-12 - let me place them side by side

| Psalm 102:25-27 | Hebrews 1:10-12 |
| --- | --- |
| In the beginning You laid the foundations of the earth, and the heavens are the work of Your hands. They will perish, but You remain; they will all wear out like a garment. Like clothing You will change them, and they will be passed on. But You remain the same, and Your years will never end. | In the beginning, O Lord, You laid the foundations of the earth, and the heavens are the work of Your hands. They will perish, but You remain; they will all wear out like a garment. You will roll them up like a robe; like a garment they will be changed; but You remain the same, and Your years will never end. |

Let us observe a few points about these quotes:

- Psalm 102:25-27 is definitely about the LORD God, V22 & 24
- Hebrews 1:10-12 is definitely about Jesus Christ
- Psalm 102 is inspired scripture and thus, the author of Psalm 102 was inspired by the Holy Spirit (2 Tim 3:16, 17, 2 Peter 1 :19-21)
- Similarly, Heb 1:10-12 is also inspired scripture and the author was inspired to write this by quoting Ps 102 and applying it to Christ.

The fact that Ps 102 is inspired to be a prayer in the mouth of a human does not alter the fact that it is inspired scripture about the LORD Jehovah which the NT reveals by the same source of inspiration to be Jesus Christ.

[Note: the author of Ps 102 is unknown; it may have been any of a number of authors of various psalms or someone else.]

Comment: **Comments have been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/151805/discussion-on-answer-by-dottard-is-god-the-speaker-of-psalm-10225-27-or-is-it-t); please do not continue the discussion here.** Before posting a comment below this one, please review the [purposes of comments](/help/privileges/comment). Comments that do not request clarification or suggest improvements usually belong as an [answer](/help/how-to-answer), on [meta], or in [chat]. Comments continuing discussion may be removed.

Answer (score 0):

The Psalm opens by identifying a speaker.

Psalm 102:1 (ESV)

> A Prayer of one afflicted, when he is faint and pours out his complaint before the LORD. Hear my prayer, O LORD; let my cry come to you!

The one who is speaking is identified as *the afflicted*. The Hebrew is [עָנִי](https://www.blueletterbible.org/lexicon/h6041/esv/wlc/0-1/). With respect to the New Testament the proper identification of עָנִי was given by Zechariah.

Zechariah 9:9

> Rejoice greatly, O daughter of Zion!
> Shout aloud, O daughter of Jerusalem!
> Behold, your king is coming to you;
> righteous and having salvation is he,
> **humble עָנִי** and mounted on a donkey,
> on a colt, the foal of a donkey.

**Conclusion**
One way of understanding Psalm 102:25-27 is to see it as speaking prophetically as the writer of the Letter to the Hebrews does.

On the other hand if one insisted on a literal and inflexible understanding of who is speaking and use the logic inherent to this question, then clearly it is the one who is humble, עָנִי, who is speaking. This is a description of Jesus, as Zechariah predicted and affirmed by Matthew (21:1-11), Mark (11:1-11), Luke (19:29-41), and John (12:12-19).

One does not have to insist it was Jesus speaking, although that would be in keeping with the OP's line of reasoning. More reasonable would be to understand the Psalmist was inspired to identify themselves only as עָנִי, not as David or Asaph or any specific individual in order to create a text which was perfectly suited to be used in the New Testament.